# How to change site title, site header and index title in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, header, django-admin, titlebar

How can I change the site title `Django site admin`, the site header `Django administration` and the index title `Site administration` in Django Admin?

[image]

Comment: This is covered in the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial07/#customize-the-admin-look-and-feel).

Comment: The best answer is [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36251770/633961)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

**Update**: If you are using Django 1.7+, see the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24983231/2198632).

---

*Original answer from 2011:*
You need to create your own admin `base_site.html` template to do this. The easiest way is to create the file:

```
/<projectdir>/templates/admin/base_site.html
```

This should be a copy of the [original `base_site.html`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html), except putting in your custom title:

```
{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">{% trans 'my cool admin console' %}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

For this to work, you need to have the correct settings for your project, namely in `settings.py`:

- Make sure `/projectdir/templates/` is added into `TEMPLATE_DIRS`.
- Make sure `django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader` is added into `TEMPLATE_LOADERS`.

[See docs for more information on `settings.py`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/).

Comment: Also note that you can `{% extends "admin/base.html" %}` in `/<projectdir>/templates/admin/base_site.html`, and simply redefine the block(s) you need, i.e. `{% block branding %}...{% endblock %}`.

Comment: even if quite old, I want to add that you must put your app where you define this template before 'django.contrib.admin', in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: @Arnaud, THAT is the cleanest answer

Comment: In django 1.6 python 3.3, the above works even when you don't add the `TEMPLATE_LOADER` setting. Just `TEMPLATE_DIR` is enough it seems

Comment: This is outdated as of 1.7. See Reto Aebersold's answer.

Comment: Try this in url.py  

admin.site.site_header = 'My Administration'

admin.site.index_title = ('My Admin')

admin.site.site_title = ('My Admin page')

Answer (score 424):

As of Django 1.7 you don't need to override templates. You can now implement [site_header](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.site_header), [`site_title`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.site_title), and [`index_title`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.index_title) attributes on a custom [AdminSite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite) in order to easily change the admin site’s page title and header text. Create an AdminSite subclass and hook your instance into your URLconf:

**admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    # Text to put at the end of each page's <title>.
    site_title = ugettext_lazy('My site admin')

    # Text to put in each page's <h1> (and above login form).
    site_header = ugettext_lazy('My administration')

    # Text to put at the top of the admin index page.
    index_title = ugettext_lazy('Site administration')

admin_site = MyAdminSite()
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include
from myproject.admin import admin_site

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^myadmin/', include(admin_site.urls)),
)
```

**Update**: As pointed out by oxfn you can simply set the [`site_header`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.site_header) in your `urls.py` or `admin.py` directly without subclassing `AdminSite`:

```
admin.site.site_header = 'My administration'
```

Comment: This throws a "You don't have permission to edit anything" error message when I try to access the /myadmin/.

Looks like I should call .autodiscover, but Django 1.7 it's supposed to be called automatically. Any clue?

Comment: @DavidArcos You need to register your models at new `admin_site` that you created. Like `admin_site.register(MyModel, ModelAdmin)`

Comment: If also a header in django.auth.views should be customized (that depends on `admin/base_site.html` template, e.g. password_reset) then also `extra_context` should be used in urls: e.g. `url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset, name='admin_password_reset', kwargs={'extra_context': {'site_header': "My administration"}})`

Comment: Something to know about this way is that it will only work with the standard admin pages, if on your side on another application you are adding your own admin pages (extendind the admin base template), they will always take the default "Django Administration" title.

Comment: @oxfn If I have more than one apps, the `admin.site.site_header` configuration in which `app*/admin.py` would take effect?

Comment: I got this error - django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Passing a 3-tuple to include() is not supported. Pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name, and provide the namespace argument to include() instead.

Comment: If you override AdminSite, you get `you dont have permission`. To solve this issue check here out:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-the-default-admin-site

Answer (score 258):

There is an easy way to set admin site header - assign it to current admin instance in `urls.py` like this

```
admin.site.site_header = 'My admin'
```

Or one can implement some header-building magic in separate method

```
admin.site.site_header = get_admin_header()
```

Thus, in simple cases there's no need to subclass `AdminSite`

Comment: I added it in my `url.py` right after urlpattern. But it didn't work when I'm running the site with nginx

Comment: @AlexJolig nginx  shouldn't be a problem. Which backenf fo you use? Did you restart it?

Comment: The first way worked. I dont really know what was the problem at the moment. thank you

Comment: If you're changing the header, you'll probably also want to change the site title, which can be accomplished with: `admin.site.site_title = 'My site admin'`.

Comment: Here is an import string to add to `urls.py`: `from django.contrib import admin`

Comment: Wish I found this first... Heeding the docs, I subclassed `AdminSite` and spent a while trying to make it work with `autodiscover()` but finally thought of this solution on my own. I actually have my override in `admin.py`, which I think is cleaner since it's kept along with all the other admin-related logic

Comment: check the list of all the attributes you can change at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-objects

Comment: even after 10 years this works, thank you. I placed it in my urls.py and it works in a custom theme.

Answer (score 173):

In `urls.py` you can override the 3 most important variables:

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.site_header = 'My project'                    # default: "Django Administration"
admin.site.index_title = 'Features area'                 # default: "Site administration"
admin.site.site_title = 'HTML title from adminsitration' # default: "Django site admin"
```

---

Reference: [Django documentation on these attributes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-attributes).

Comment: This should be the CORRECT answer to this question. This is the most appropriated and elegant solution.

Comment: is there's a way to having `username`  of logged-in user with title of *index* for example:
`admin.site.index_title = request.user.username+' Features area'`

Answer (score 73):

A simple complete solution in Django 1.8.3 based on answers in this question.

In `settings.py` add:

```
ADMIN_SITE_HEADER = "My shiny new administration"
```

In `urls.py` add:

```
from django.conf import settings
admin.site.site_header = settings.ADMIN_SITE_HEADER
```

Comment: Is there a better place to do this than using urls.py ?

Comment: @VenkatKotra Yes, in `admin.py`. If you don't already have it, just create it and don't forget to add `from django.contrib import admin`.

Comment: The recommended way to import settings is via - "from django.conf import settings" (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code)

Comment: There is no setting that Django looks at called `ADMIN_SITE_HEADER`, the only thing that matters here is the line in `urls.py`

Comment: I followed this way and have the named defined in settings first then imported into the url.py as explained above. I did the same for the login and the html title and all three worked well.
==> **in url.py:**


{{ from django.conf import settings }}

admin.site.site_header = settings.ADMIN_SITE_HEADER
admin.site.site_title = settings.ADMIN_SITE_TITLE
admin.site.index_title = settings.ADMIN_SITE_INDEX

Answer (score 24):

For Django 2.1.1 add following lines to `urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Admin Site Config
admin.sites.AdminSite.site_header = 'My site admin header'
admin.sites.AdminSite.site_title = 'My site admin title'
admin.sites.AdminSite.index_title = 'My site admin index'
```

Answer (score 23):

The easiest way of doing it 
make sure you have

```
from django.contrib import admin
```

and then just add these at bottom of `url.py` of you main application

```
admin.site.site_title = "Your App Title"
admin.site.site_header = "Your App Admin"
```

Answer (score 21):

Hope am not too late to the party, The easiest would be to edit the admin.py file.

```
admin.site.site_header = 'your_header'
admin.site.site_title = 'site_title'
admin.site.index_title = 'index_title'
```

Answer (score 16):

Simple Method is add following code in your ***url.py***

```
    urlpatterns = [
    #Your URLS here
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

admin.site.site_header = 'SiteName Admin'
admin.site.site_title  = 'SiteName'
admin.site.index_title   = 'Admin'
```

Answer (score 10):

As you can see in the [templates](http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/branches/releases/1.3.X/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html), the text is delivered via the localization framework (note the use of the `trans` template tag). You can make changes to the translation files to override the text without making your own copy of the templates.

1. `mkdir locale`
2. `./manage.py makemessages`
3. Edit `locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`, adding these lines:

   ```
   msgid "Django site admin"
   msgstr "MySite site admin"

   msgid "Django administration"
   msgstr "MySite administration"
   ```
4. `./manage.py compilemessages`

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/localization/#message-files

Comment: This is a terrible solution. Overriding translation strings is just an awful idea.

Answer (score 9):

From **Django 2.0** you can just add a single line in the `url.py` and change the name.

```py
# url.py

from django.contrib import admin 
admin.site.site_header = "My Admin Central" # Add this
```

For older versions of **Django. (<1.11 and earlier)** you need to edit `admin/base_site.html`

Change this line

```html
{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Django site admin') }}{% endblock %}
```

to

```html
{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Your Site name Admin Central') }}{% endblock %}
```

You can check your `django` version by

```sh
django-admin --version
```

Answer (score 8):

There are two methods to do this:

1] By overriding `base_site.html` in `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html`:
Following is the content of `base_site.html`:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Django site admin') }}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{{ site_header|default:_('Django administration') }}</a></h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

Edit the site_title & site_header in the above code snippet. This method works but it is not recommendable since its a static change.

2] By adding following lines in `urls.py` of project's directory:

```
admin.site.site_header = "AppHeader"
admin.site.site_title = "AppTitle"
admin.site.index_title = "IndexTitle"
admin.site.site_url = "Url for view site button"
```

This method is recommended one since we can change the site-header, site-title & index-title without editing `base_site.html`.

Answer (score 8):

Use `format_html` to allow html to be rendered, otherwise it will be just plain text.

in your main `urls.py` file add followings(`urls.py` is in the directory where `settings.py` exist):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.html import format_html

site_header = 'Your html snippet'
admin.site.site_header = format_html(site_header)
```

Comment: is There's a way to get the `username` of the logged-in user for example
`admin.site.index_title = request.user.username + ' Admin`

Answer (score 7):

**admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite

AdminSite.site_title = ugettext_lazy('My Admin')

AdminSite.site_header = ugettext_lazy('My Administration')

AdminSite.index_title = ugettext_lazy('DATA BASE ADMINISTRATION')
```

Comment: `from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy`

Don't forget to add this line.

Answer (score 7):

Just go to admin.py file and add this line in the file :

`admin.site.site_header = "My Administration"`

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you should add templates/admin/base_site.html to your project. This file can safely be overwritten since it’s a file that the Django devs have intended for the exact purpose of customizing your admin site a bit. Here’s an example of what to put in the file:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {% trans 'Some Organisation' %}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<style type="text/css">
  #header
  {
    /* your style here */
  }
</style>
<h1 id="site-name">{% trans 'Organisation Website' %}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

This is common practice. But I noticed after this that I was still left with an annoying “Site Administration” on the main admin index page. And this string was not inside any of the templates, but rather set inside the admin view. Luckily it’s quite easy to change. Assuming your language is set to English, run the following commands from your project directory:

```
$ mkdir locale
$ ./manage.py makemessages -l en
```

Now open up the file locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po and add two lines after the header information (the last two lines of this example)

```
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2010-04-03 03:25+0200\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

msgid "Site administration"
msgstr "Main administration index"
```

After this, remember to run the following command and reload your project’s server:

```
$ ./manage.py compilemessages
```

source: http://overtag.dk/wordpress/2010/04/changing-the-django-admin-site-title/

Comment: Linking to outside sites is considered bad, since the link might go bad. You are encouraged to rewrite the answer from the site here.

Comment: I rewrote the answer in case you don't wanna go outside site.

Answer (score 6):

You can use these following lines in your main `urls.py`

you can add the text in the quotes to be displayed

To replace the text Django admin use `admin.site.site_header = ""`

To replace the text Site Administration use `admin.site.site_title = ""`

To replace the site name you can use `admin.site.index_title = ""`

To replace the url of the view site button you can use `admin.site.site_url = ""`

Answer (score 5):

you do not need to change any template for this work you just need to update the `settings.py` of your project. Go to the bottom of the `settings.py` and define this.

```
admin.site.site_header = 'My Site Admin'
```

In this way you would be able to change the header of the  of the Django admin. Moreover you can read more about Django Admin customization and settings on the following link.

[Django Admin Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `AdminSite.site_header` to change that text. Here is the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.site_header)

Answer (score 5):

In `admin.py` file just override these attributes

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.site_header = "site header name"
admin.site.index_title = "index title name"
admin.site.site_title = "site title name"
```

Answer (score 4):

You just override the `admin/base_site.html` template (copy the template from `django.contrib.admin.templates` and put in your own admin template dir) and replace the `branding` block.

Answer (score 4):

Since I only use admin interface in my app, I put this in the admin.py :

```
admin.site.site_header = 'My administration'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change [site title](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.site_title), [site header](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.site_header) and [index title](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.index_title) in Django Admin as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.site_title = 'My site title'
admin.site.site_header = 'My site header'
admin.site.index_title = 'My index title'
```

Then, these are changed as shown below:

[image]

In addition, you can translate them with [gettext_lazy()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy) as shown below. *[gettext()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext) doesn't work for them and you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467626/whats-the-correct-way-to-set-up-django-translation/76475418#76475418) explaining how to translate in Django:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

admin.site.site_title = _('My site title')
admin.site.site_header = _('My site header')
admin.site.index_title = _('My index title')
```

Then, these are translated as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One easy method is to include the following code in the urls.py file located in your project folder.

```
 in urls.py add 

  admin.site.site_header  =  "Site Header here"  
  admin.site.site_title  =  "Side title"
  admin.site.index_title  =  "Index title"
```

For example:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


admin.site.site_header  =  "Hadramawt Kitchen"  
admin.site.site_title  =  "Hadramawt Kitchen"
admin.site.index_title  =  "Hadramawt Admin"

urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('', include('food_products.urls' )),
  path('categories', include('categories.urls' )),
  path('news', include('news.urls')),
  path('weeklyOffer', include('weekly_offer.urls'))
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```