# Change header 'Django administration' text on nginx

Tags: django, nginx, django-admin, gunicorn

I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938491/django-admin-change-header-django-administration-text)'s answers to change my django admin panel title header.

I tried this:

> There is an easy way to set admin site header - assign it to current
>   admin instance in urls.py like this
>
> `admin.site.site_header = 'My admin'`

But it just works when I'm **running the page via `Python manage.py runserver`**

My question is how can I change the admin title header when I'm running the site via `gunicorn` and `nginx`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

writing this code at the bottom of `urls.py` somehow worked:

```
admin.site.site_header = 'My admin'
```

Answer (score 4):

If you already have an admin.py file started wherein you have registered your particular models, you can simply adjust these values there.

your_app/admin.py

```
# Simple admin setup
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel
# Register model
admin.site.register(MyModel)
# Tweak admin site settings like title, header, 'View Site' URL, etc
admin.site.site_title = 'My App Admin'
admin.site.site_header = 'My App Admin'
```

You can find all the attributes [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-objects).

Answer (score 3):

follow the below steps to customize the site header and site title text of django admin login page :

1.)First import admin module in settings.py file like as below :

```
from django.contrib import admin
```

2.)In bottom of settings.py file add these lines:

```
admin.site.site_header = 'MY_SITE_HEADER'
admin.site.site_title = 'MY_SITE_TITLE'
```

The above method works in latest version of django i.e.1.11.3 till date.

Answer (score 1):

You can make changes to parts of the admin by providing a template in an admin subdir of your templates directory to override what is provided by admin.

In this case, you'd want to provide a base_site.html template. You can see what the default one looks like here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html