# Passing In Value for Title Variable in Django Template

Tags: python, django, templates

I am dealing with the following code in a Django template:

```
<!-- Override title of base -->
{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Hello World') }}{% endblock %}
```

For the Django admin web site, the value of the title variable above (i.e. `{{ title }}`) defaults to "Log in". Where is this value being defined? I would like to change this value but pass it in rather than hard code it.

Comment: For login/logout/password reset templates, the `title` is defined in `django.contrib.auth.views`.

Comment: How can I override this value by passing in a value for the variable instead of hard coding the value in the template?

Comment: I think you'll need to replace those views with your own. But in that case, hard-coding the value of `title` in the templates seems like a far better and easier option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the variable {{title}} in the template and use the view to pass the content, like this:

```
template.html
<title>{{ title }}</title>

views.py
def something(request):
    #Do something
    return render_to_response('template.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request,{'title':'Here is what you want to show as title'}))
```

Comment: Anyway to accomplish this by defining a constant instead of changing a view? I'd prefer not to override a view since I'm using the views in django.contrib.auth.views.

Comment: maybe this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091924/django-admin-change-header-django-administration-text-on-nginx