# Path to template directory not working in settings.py

Tags: python, django

Currently created a **templates** folder inside my project folder.

Then I added the admin folder and the file `base_site.html` to be able to change the Django admin title:

```
Home / Django / mysite / templates / admin / base_site.html
```

However, it doesn't change. My `settings.py` file below:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Of Avinash Raj's request:

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

Comment: try `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/admin')]`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Thanks. But it didn't work.

Comment: post the contents of `urls.py`, `views.py`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Django 1.7 you do not need to rewrite any templates to change admin title or header but just set `site_header`, `site_title`, and `index_title` in `admin.py` & then hook them in `urls.py`. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24983231/5253807