# django: instantiating AdminSite changes not reflected

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to change the templates of admin site, and tried overriding by creating a local template for admin, but failed without knowing why: [template way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39132187/django-how-do-i-actually-override-admin-site-template?noredirect=1#comment65613565_39132187). So now I tried to create a instance of AdminSite and make changes from there, but still failed. I have:

```
urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^myadmin/', admin.site.urls),

admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Equipment, Calibration, Flag, Tests
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    site_header = "Equipment Calibration Database"
    site_title = "Equipment Calibration Database"
    index_title = "Equipment Calibration Database"
# Register your models here.
admin_site = MyAdminSite(name = 'myadmin')

admin.site.register(Equipment)
admin.site.register(Calibration)
admin.site.register(Flag)
admin.site.register(Tests)
```

Now when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/myadmin/, I still find that none of the text I specified in MyAdminSite is in effect, I still see "Django administration" and "Site administration".

This is all acting really weird and helps are greatly welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the text in the admin, all you need to add to the `admin.py` is as follows:

```
admin.site.site_header = "Equipment Calibration Database"
admin.site.site_title = "Equipment Calibration Database"
admin.site.index_title = "Equipment Calibration Database"
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! Do you know why the template way I did in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39132187/django-how-do-i-actually-override-admin-site-template?noredirect=1#comment65613565_39132187 doesn't work by any chance?

Comment: I'm guessing because the way you did it was for an older version of Django, they made it simpler recently (the code I posted above)