# Replacing django-admin's bootstrap theme's default logo

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-staticfiles

I have generated a django-admin for my app and I can access the dashboard. But it contains a logo that says "django admin". I want to change it to my own custom logo. How can I do that?

I have tried adding a base.html file to admin directory and tried to override but for some reason it's not working. It's code is as follows:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load theming_tags %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block blockbots %}
    {{ block.super }}
    {# Using blockbots ensures theming css comes after any form media and other css #}
    {% render_theming_css %}
    <style type="text/css">
    #header #branding h1 {
        background-image: url("bootstrap_admin/img/logo-140x60.png");
    }
    </style>
{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}" class="django-admin-logo">
    <!-- Django Administration -->
    <img src="{% static "bootstrap_admin/img/logo-140x60.png" %}" alt="{{ site_header|default:_('Django Admin') }}">
</a>
{% endblock branding %}
```

[image: screenshot]

I want to change the logo in the top-left corner. How can I achieve what I'm trying to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938491/django-admin-change-header-django-administration-text)

`"{% static "bootstrap_admin/img/logo-140x60.png" %}"`
this comes from here

> django-admin-bootstrap/bootstrap_admin/static/bootstrap_admi‌​n/img/logo-140x60.pn‌​g

after replacing you need to run command `python manage.py collectstatic`then this will work

Comment: I have already visited that post. It works fine for title but I'm not sure how to change it to work for logo. Any suggestion?

Comment: if so, then you can always use the third-party packages for django-admin. they also provide many cool features to use

Comment: I have searched a lot but found nothing. Could you point me to something?

Comment: did you use django-admin-tool ?

Comment: if this answer helped you then you can always accept the answer or upvote.

Comment: I know that but I'm still stuck where I was. I have read docs for django-admin-tool but couldn't figure out how to change the logo. Can you direct me a little more?

As you can see in the code I shared in the question, I had already used those `theming-tags` that you called `django-admin-tool-theming` but it doesn't work.

Comment: so basically you want to change header 'Django Administration'
 right  ? can you upload the picture of which specific part you want to change?

Comment: Just copy /django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html from django source [link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html) and paste it under your templates directory. _yourproject/templates/admin/basesite.html_ Now you can change whatever you like in this template.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have edited the question with the screenshot. I want to change the logo in the top-left corner, namely `django-admin`

Comment: this is not default Django admin can you tell which third party app are you using?

Comment: I’m using django-admin-bootstrap. It can be found at https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrap/django-admin-bootstrap

Comment: you need to change base_site.html this file. you can found wherever you installed it `django-admin-bootstrapped/django_admin_bootstrapped/templates/admin/base_site.htm`l you can create admin/admin_title.html then it will automatically replaced by admi_title.html

Comment: Alright. Lemme try it and then I’ll get back to you. And just so you know, I have even tried to replace the .png file of the logo in the installed directory of the django-admin-bootstrap package (the directory where this package is actually installed), but that didn’t work either. And this is extremely confusing because I have no idea where else is it loading that png file from.

Comment: Are you talking about this "{% static "bootstrap_admin/img/logo-140x60.png" %}" this comes from here django-admin-bootstrap/bootstrap_admin/static/bootstrap_admin/img/logo-140x60.png after replacing you need to run command collectstatic then this will work.

Comment: It worked man. I wasn't running `collectstatic` after replacing the logo file. Thanks. Marking your answer as `ACCEPTED`.

Comment: glad could help you :)

Answer (score 1):

The official way to achieve that is:
You need to override the default templates provided by Django. In your Django settings, your code:: TEMPLATES setting looks like this.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

This means that Django will look for templates in a directory called `templates` inside each app, but you can override that by setting a value for `TEMPLATES.DIRS.`

We change the `'DIRS': [],` to `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/')],` and create the templates folder. If your `STATICFILES_DIRS` is empty set it to:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

Now create a file called `base_site.html` from the admin app to templates\admin folder you just created. Add the code in it:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Django site admin') }}{% 
endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">
<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">
    <img src="{% static 'Your image.png' %}" height="40px" />
</a>
 </h1>
 {% endblock %}

 {% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```