# django how to add logo in admin site

Tags: django

cant override the django admin site page, i just want to put a logo in my admin page, did i miss something in my code?

I already run, `python manage.py collectstatic` and ofcourse that logo image is exist in my static folder

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')


import os

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

[image]

template

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Django site admin') }}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">
    <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">
        <img src="{% static 'logo.png' %}" height="40px" />
    </a>
</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Did you add `STATICFILES_DIRS` as `static`?

Comment: yeah, did i miss something in my code @toRex

Answer (score 0):

### Your question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46198820/replacing-django-admins-bootstrap-themes-default-logo)

If your `STATICFILES_DIRS` is empty set it to:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

See [more](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/logo.html) explation.

Comment: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.`

Comment: Don't you have a static file?

Comment: Give a try by setting image path like `{% static 'img/logo.png' %}` and before that add a new folder name `img` in static and paste the logo in `img` folder