# How to change the name of the Django admin page?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, rename

I'm studying Django. I saw django tutorial part7 and I wanted to rename the name of the django admin page. So, I did it but it hasn't worked.....

**mysite/mysite/settings.py**:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**mysite/templates/admin/base_site.html**:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Django site admin') }}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{{ site_header|default:_('mysite') }}</a></h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

I renamed to mysite from Django administration.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to do

```
{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Mysite</a></h1>
{% endblock %}
```

> Better way

Simply go to urls.py of your project and add this outside urlpatterns.

```
admin.site.site_header = 'My Site Admin Panel'
admin.site.site_title = 'My Site Title'
```

make sure, below line is included at top.

```
from django.contrib import admin
```

Answer (score 24):

Use this part of code in your `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.site_title = "<your_title>"
admin.site.site_header = "<your_header>"
admin.site.index_title = "<your_index_title>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change [site title](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.site_title), [site header](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.site_header) and [index title](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.index_title) in Django Admin as shown below. *You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938491/how-to-change-site-title-site-header-and-index-title-in-django-admin/76500101#76500101) explaining it in detail:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.site_title = 'My site title'
admin.site.site_header = 'My site header'
admin.site.index_title = 'My index title'
```