# Changing the Django admin site

Tags: python, django, admin

I wanted to change the "Django administration" text on the default Django admin site. But the docs do not make it that, clear. Is there a way that I can do it once i have collected all the static files?

Comment: Please, check this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938491/django-admin-change-header-django-administration-text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
admin.site.site_header = "your Admin name "
admin.site.site_title = "Your Admin Portal"
admin.site.index_title = "Welcome to YOur Researcher Portal"
```

In The admins.py file

1. First change the header

   Second will channge the title

   Third will change the index tilte